# Protractor: element.getText() returns an object and not String

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor

I have an element defined as

```
this.clientRowName = element(by.id('CLIENT_NAME')); //page object file
```

I want to read the text in this element which is "ABC" but doing:
    var client = page.clientRowName.getText();

returns an object instead of a string. Is there any other way that I can get the text for the element

Answer (score 110, accepted):

**[`getText()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText) returns a promise**, you need to **resolve** it:

```
page.clientRowName.getText().then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```

Or, if you just want to assert the text, let `expect()` resolve the promise for you:

```
expect(page.clientRowName.getText()).toEqual("ABC");
```

[Promises and the Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md#promises-and-the-control-flow) documentation page should clear things up.

Comment: If you are using Chai expectations, it has a `.eventually` method to resolve a promise and get the value from inside it.  `expect(page.clientRowName.getText()).to.eventually.equal("ABC")`

Comment: hi everyone, can I use getText function in  toEqual() or toBe() ? like that : *expect(element.getText()).toEqual(element2.getText())*

Answer (score 4):

Another solution may be to use `async/await`.

```
class Page {
  constructor() {
    this.clientRowName = $('#CLIENT_NAME');
  }
}

/****************/

it('should console.log client name', async () => {
  const client = await Page.clientRowName.getText();
  console.log(client);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually used `element.getAttribute('value')`

Comment: `.getAttribute('value')` may not work. Yo can also try `.getAttribute('textContent')` or `.getAttribute('innerText')`

Answer (score 0):

## If you're in 2021, you will want to read this answer

according to protractors documentation, [.getText()](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText) returns a promise.

The best way to handle a promise, as of 2021, is to use async/await keywords. This will make Protractor 'freeze' and wait, until the promise is resolved before running the next command

```
it('test case 1', async () => {
  let text = await page.clientRowName.getText();
  console.log(text);
})
```

`.then()` can also be used, but using `async/await` will make your code a lot more readable and easier to debug.