# toEqual by binding is not working

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have to assert the text by the below:

```
expect(accessPolicyPage.accessPolicyName).toEqual(element.all(by.binding("pol.name")).get(0).getText());
```

It is giving me some long error as below.

> Expected 'Access Policy Name 01' to equal ({ ptor_: ({ controlFlow:
>   Function, schedule: Function, setFileDetector: Function, getSession:
>   Function, getCapabilities: Function, quit: Function, actions:
>   Function, touchActions: Function, executeScript: Function,
>   executeAsyncScript: Function, call: Function, wait: Function, sleep:
>   Function, getWindowHandle: Function, getAllWindowHandles: Function,
>   getPageSource: Function, close: Function, getCurrentUrl: Function,
>   getTitle: Function, findElementInternal_: Function,
>   findElementsInternal_: Function, takeScreenshot: Function, manage:
>   Function, switc

Answer (score 1):

What you see printed on the console is a "scary" *promise* object representation. If you need a real value, *resolve the promise explicitly* with `then()`:

```
element.all(by.binding("pol.name")).get(0).getText().then(function (text) {
    expect(accessPolicyPage.accessPolicyName).toEqual(text);
});
```

---

Or, since `accessPolicyPage.accessPolicyName` is an actual text defined beforehand, you can just swap the things in the matcher and *let `expect()` resolve the promise implicitly*:

```
expect(element.all(by.binding("pol.name")).get(0).getText()).toEqual(accessPolicyPage.accessPolicyName);
```

This option is simpler and generally recommended.

Answer (score 1):

In fact Protractor supports expectations for promises. But it only handles case, when first argument in expectation is promise. So following should work:

```
expect(somePromise).toEqual(someString);
expect(somePromise).toEqual(anotherPromise);
```

But this one won't:

```
expect(notPromise).toEqual(somePromise);
```

Answer (score 0):

getText() return a promise and not text,which needs to be handled.

[Protractor: element.getText() returns an object and not String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478905/protractor-element-gettext-returns-an-object-and-not-string)