# How to process a promise and get access to element and use getText()

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, mocha.js, appium, chai

I'm trying to reconstruct and run hybrid apps tests by `Appium + Protractor` using example [here](https://github.com/appium-boneyard/sample-code/tree/master/sample-code/examples/node)
My global goal is make a test framework for hybrid/native apps based `Appium + Protractor`
My local goal is understand how to integrate `Appium + Protractor` and choose a best approaches.
But at the start I meet an obstacle to get text from element and compare with expected. I can't to get text from `WebView` element and compare with expected by default methods `elementByXpath.getText();`

So, I added a new test to [file](https://github.com/appium-boneyard/sample-code/blob/master/sample-code/examples/node/android-webview.js)

```
it("equal text", function () {
    return driver
        .elementById('buttonStartWebviewCD')
        .click()
        .sleep(5000)
        .contexts()
        .then(function (ctxs) {
            console.log(ctxs);
            return driver.context(ctxs[ctxs.length - 1]);
        })
        .source().then(function (source) {
            source.should.include('Prefered Car');
        })
        .elementById('name_input')
        .clear()
        .sendKeys('Andrey')
        .sendKeys(wd.SPECIAL_KEYS.Return)
        .sleep(2000)
        .elementByXPath("//h2").getText()
        .then(function(text) {
            console.log(text);
        });
});
```

I found similar situation with my [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627969/protractor-element-gettext-returns-an-object-but-not-string)
but it doesn't help me.
Error:

> driver.elementById(...).click(...).sleep(...).contexts(...).then(...).source(...).then(...).elementById(...).clear(...).sendKeys(...).sendKeys(...).sleep(...).elementByXPath(...).getText is not a function
>       at Context. (sample-code\examples\node\android- 
>       webview.js:152:28)
>       at _fulfilled (sample- 
>       code\examples\node\node_modules\wd\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
>       at C:\protractor\sample-code\sample- 
>       code\examples\node\node_modules\wd\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (sample- 
>       code\examples\node\node_modules\wd\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
>       at C:\protractor\sample-code\sample- 
>       code\examples\node\node_modules\wd\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
>       at runSingle (sample- 
>       code\examples\node\node_modules\wd\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
>       at flush (sample- 
>       code\examples\node\node_modules\wd\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)

Help me to resolve this problem

Comment: So it looks like the "example here" is not a Protractor example...it uses wd (https://www.npmjs.com/package/wd)

Comment: @cnishina I'm not agree with you cause in official Protractor doc (relate with mobile) I found a code example and I used in my case.