# for loop in protractor js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have a scenario where there are repeating elements with classname `.product-tile` and I am trying to get the elements by that class name and loop through each of them and finding the element whose title is `Products`.

If so, I'm trying clicking on `apt-add-to-cart-button`, but here the code isn't going in for loop.

```
     var products = element.all(by.css('.product-tile'));
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    var product = products.get(0);
    if (product.element(by.css('.productName .title')).getText() === 'Products') {
        product.element(by.css('apt-add-to-cart-button')).click();
    }
}
```

html :

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can't use `getText()` in this way. `getText()` needs to resolve promise and then should be used.

Comment: Also, please mention if any error is happening.

Comment: @demouser123   there isn't any error

Answer (score 1):

actually the repeating selector should be resolved as a promise like below

```
element.all(by.css('.product-tile.ng-scope')).then(function(items){
    console.log(items.length); //will get the length here

// do the stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478905/protractor-element-gettext-returns-an-object-and-not-string) through, as `getText()` returns a promise which needs to be resolved.

You may need something like this

```
var products = element.all(by.css('.product-tile.ng-scope'));
for (var i = 0; i <= products.length; i++) {
console.log(i);
var product = products.get(0);
if (product.element(by.css('.productName .title')).getText().then(function(returnText){
    if(returnText==='Products'){
   product.element(by.css('apt-add-to-cart-button')).click();
}else{
   console.log('Something happened');
}

 });
 }
```

Edit - Your class contains compound class, so you cannot use a single class inside your CSS selector. Please see updated code

Comment: I'm not getting console.log(i) output

Comment: Please add relevant HTML in the question body.

Comment: same result..
products.length is showing undefined when I console.