# Protractor - Selenium element Angular 2 Typescript

Tags: html, angular, selenium, protractor

ive got some troubles with getting text from div which has got class name and id, I tried
`element(by.css('.panel-body')).getText();<-return object Objct
 element(by.className('panel-body')).getText();<-return object Object
element(by.id('message-body')).getText();<-return object Object
element(by.xpath('//*[@id="message-body"]/text()[3]')).getText()<-return textObject`
there is [image: HTML view, I need to get this link 0.0.0.0:3000...]

HTML view, I need to get this link 0.0.0.0:3000 into string, Can you help me? Thanks:)

Comment: Ok, getText returns promise, is there any way to extract string from that object?

Comment: you have to resolve the promise. pls refer this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478905/protractor-element-gettext-returns-an-object-and-not-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to extract the URL:

```
element(by.css('#message-body'))
  .getText()
  .then(text => text.match(/[^"\s]+\/student\/register\/\?[^"\s]+/)[0])
  .then(url => console.log(url));
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know maybe how to return this url out of that function? Its undefined when I return it inside .then, and when I return all element with return inside .then it returns object of element :)

Comment: You are dealing with asynchronous calls, thus it's not possible to directly get the result from a function. That said, the function returns a `Promise` that can be resolved with `.then`. So if you wish to use the `url` elsewhere, then store it in a global variable or return the `Promise` and resolve it when you need the value.