# Passing text from HTML as variable using protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have a table with unknown values (which I need to log in later) and I would like to save one of it with class `currentWeek` to a variable. HTML is as following:

```
<tr _ngcontent-c21="" class="currentWeek">
    <th _ngcontent-c21="" class="text-center">Value1Foo</th>
    (...)
</tr>
```

In proctracor I created in `Helper.ts`:

```
static getfooOfTheWeek() {
    let child = element(by.css('.currentWeek')).$('.text-center');

    describe('Get foo', function () {
        it('get foo', function () {
            browser.driver.get('tablepage');
            browser.sleep(3000);
            return ((child).getText()).toString();
        })
    })
}
```

and in file maintest.ts:

```
describe('Get FOO', function () {
    var FOO=Helper.getfooOfTheWeek();
    browser.sleep(2000);
    //use the value set in Helper.getfooOfTheWeek();
    NegativeTest.SomeTest(FOO);
});
```

but it fails ususally with `- Failed: each key must be a number of string; got undefined` - therefore I think the `FOO` is save as an Object, not as string.

I thought also using JSON (to use `JSON.parse()`), but developers can't gives the values to the table from JSON

Any path what I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - found this issue about saving as string instead of object: [Protractor: element.getText() returns an object and not String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478905/protractor-element-gettext-returns-an-object-and-not-string) where I need to resolve the promise

and instead of passing it as variable with `var FOO=Helper.getfooOfTheWeek();` I saved it as `browser.params.Foo`

```
static getfooOfTheWeek() {
    let child = element(by.css('.currentWeek')).$('.text-center');

    browser.driver.get('tablepage');
    browser.sleep(3000);
    child.getText().then(function(text) {
        browser.params.Foo=text;
    });
}
```

and I can run `NegativeTest.SomeTest();` where the variable is passed in `SomeTest()` as  `browser.params.Foo` (instead of writting there `FOO`)