# How to fetch the text from span tag?

Tags: javascript, xpath, selector

I need to fetch text 'Finance' from the span tag below to compare that with another value which is saved in a file.But I am not able to fetch that.

```
<span class="panel-text col-md-8">Finance</span>
```

Here is the full code for the above

```
<efx-dashboard-panel> <div class="dashboard-panel dashboard-type-employee-input">
            <div class="dashboard-panel-header">
              <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
              <span class="dashboard-panel-title">Provided Employee Input</span>
            </div>
            <div class="dashboard-panel-content">

<!----><div class="ng-star-inserted">
 <!---->
 <!----><div class="col-md-12 ng-star-inserted">
   <span class="panel-text label col-md-4">Department in which the employee works:</span><span class="panel-text col-md-8">Finance</span>
 </div>
</div><div class="ng-star-inserted">
 <!---->
 <!----><div class="col-md-12 ng-star-inserted">
   <span class="panel-text label col-md-4">Employee's Date of Birth:</span><span class="panel-text col-md-8">03-08-1990</span>
 </div>
</div><div class="ng-star-inserted">
 <!---->
 <!----><div class="col-md-12 ng-star-inserted">
   <span class="panel-text label col-md-4">County in which the employee works:</span><span class="panel-text col-md-8">Iowa</span>
 </div>
</div><div class="ng-star-inserted">
 <!---->
 <!----><div class="col-md-12 ng-star-inserted">
   <span class="panel-text label col-md-4">Employee's home address:</span><span class="panel-text col-md-8">Station Street</span>
 </div>
</div><div class="ng-star-inserted">
 <!---->
 <!----><div class="col-md-12 ng-star-inserted">
   <span class="panel-text label col-md-4">Employee ID:</span><span class="panel-text col-md-8">M1669</span>
 </div>
</div><div class="ng-star-inserted">
 <!---->
 <!----><div class="col-md-12 ng-star-inserted">
   <span class="panel-text label col-md-4">Authorization Code:</span><span class="panel-text col-md-8">45637</span>
 </div>
</div>

            </div>
          </div></efx-dashboard-panel>
```

The xpath selector for the above code is given below

```
element(by.xpath('//*[@id="employer-call"]/div[2]/div[2]/efx-tabs/div/efx-tab[4]/div/div/employee-input-panel/efx-dashboard-panel/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[2]'));
```

How can I get the text from the tag.I tried using text(),getText() and innerHTML.

Comment: May I know the reason for negative vote?

Comment: I guess it's because 1) There is no tag for programming language/tool, 2) No code for *How exactly you tried text(),getText() and innerHTML*, 3) Provided piece of HTML is just for target element while XPath includes a lot of ancestor nodes, so there is no possibility to check whether your expression is correct or not...

Comment: Depending on selectors that complex is a *really* bad idea. It makes your code very fragile: you won't be able to change anything in your HTML without worrying about breaking that selection.  Save yourself a lot of headaches and put some identifiers into the DOM.

Comment: @DanielBeck Thanks..But I can't change that because I am a tester who is testing the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution by refering to

[Solution](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478905/protractor-element-gettext-returns-an-object-and-not-string)

I used `expect(this.deptData.getText()).to.eventually.equal(employee.department);`

to fetch the data from span tag and compare that with the data in employee.department

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
//span[normalize-space()="Department in which the employee works:"]
 /following-sibling::span[1]
```

will select the `span` sibling immediately following the `span` whose space-normalized string value is `"Department in which the employee works:"`.

You can append `/text()` to select only the text nodes for the above `span`, or wrap the entire XPath expression in `string()` to take its string value.

Comment: Sorry, was still editing.  It works now.  Check it out.  Main point is that you can select based upon a label rather than a long chain of ancestors which would be more likely to change with page updates.

Comment: how to get the text from the xpath?

Comment: See my note on `/text()` or `string( XPath expression )`.

Comment: Can someone help to find why this is not working for me

Comment: I had done `element(by.xpath('//*[@id="employer-call"]/div[2]/div[2]/efx-tabs/div/efx-tab[4]/div/div/employee-input-panel/efx-dashboard-panel/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[2]/text()'));`

Comment: @kjhughescan you help on the above