# protractor element(by.binding('***')).getText() return a object instead of string

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

For below protractor mocha test cases, greeting.getText() will always return
    below result instead of the string. Could anyone give me clue on this?

```
   describe('angularjs home', function () {
        it('Should welcome a user', function (done) {
            browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
            element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys('tanshuai');    
            var greeting = element(by.binding('yourName'));
            console.log(greeting.getText());
            expect(greeting.getText()).to.eventually.equal('Hello tanshuai!');
        });
    });
```

The console.log output================

```
  ElementFinder {
      browser_:
       ProtractorBrowser {
         controlFlow: [Function],
         schedule: [Function],
         setFileDetector: [Function],
         getExecutor: [Function],
      ................................
      getId: [Function],
      takeScreenshot: [Function] }
```

Comment: `getText()` returns a promise, you need to resolve it:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Protractor: element.getText() returns an object and not String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478905/protractor-element-gettext-returns-an-object-and-not-string/29478932)

Looks like `getText()` returns a promise and you need to resolve it. Check out the link above

Comment: Hi Chirs, Thanks.         greeting.getText().then(function (text) {          console.log(text);        });  works for me. It print the expected result.    But how to let expect() resolve the promise?    expect(greeting.getText()).equal('Hello tanshuai!');  still did not work

Comment: glad to hear it!