# Assertion not being called in Protractor code

Tags: protractor

I am new to Protractor and trying my sample code; but struggling to get the Assertion working in Protractor.
Even in some cases, `getText()` of an element is returning an Object Array though in the page, there is only one element having the attribute.

## Example of the Code:

```
describe('Launch Zoo Adaption Website and Provide Text Value',function()
{
    beforeEach(async function(){
        await browser.get("http://www.thetestroom.com/jswebapp/index.html");
    });



    it('Launch Zoo Adaption Website',async function()
    {
        var some_name = 'Zoo Adoption | Home';
        some_name = browser.getTitle().then(async function(webpagetitle){
            await console.log("Title:"+webpagetitle);
        if (webpagetitle === 'Zoo Adoption | Home'){
         return 'Some Other Name';
        }
        else{
        return 'Some Name';
            }
        });
        await expect(some_name).toEqual('Some Other Name');
        //var ExpectedHomePageTitle='Zoo Adoption | Home';
        //browser.driver.sleep(3000);
        //await console.log("Actual Title:"+browser.getTitle());
        //browser.driver.sleep(3000);
        //await expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Zoo Adoption | Home');
    });

    it('Provide Textfield value in Zoo Adaption HomePage',async function()
    {
        var ExpectedTextinInputField='Hello India';
        await element(by.model("person.name")).sendKeys(ExpectedTextinInputField);
        await element(by.binding("person.name")).getText().then(async function(text){
            console.log("Expected Text:"+text);
            await expect(text).toEqual(ExpectedTextinInputField);
        });
        await console.log("Actual text displayed in dynamic field:"+(element(by.binding('person.name'))).getText());
    });
});
```

## Console Output:

> Started Title:Zoo Adoption | Home .Expected Text:Hello India Actual
>   text displayed in dynamic field:[object Object]
>
> .
>
> 2 specs, 0 failures
>   Finished in 3.695 seconds

Please help me understand:

a. Why there is no Assertion happening for my code?

b. Why getText() is returning Array of Object?

Comment: How do you know assertion is not happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor: element.getText() returns an object and not String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478905/protractor-element-gettext-returns-an-object-and-not-string)

Comment: As in the output, I can't see any comments related to Assertions.
Because if any assertion has taken place then I expect to see something like 1 assertion or 2 assertion in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
describe('Launch Zoo Adaption Website and Provide Text Value',function()
{
    beforeEach(async function(){
        await browser.get("http://www.thetestroom.com/jswebapp/index.html");
    });
    it('Launch Zoo Adaption Website',async function()
    {
       var title = browser.getTitle();
       expect(title).toEqual('Zoo Adoption | Home');
    });
it('Provide Textfield value in Zoo Adaption HomePage',async function()
    {
         var ExpectedTextinInputField='Hello India';
        await element(by.css("input[type=""]")).sendKeys(ExpectedTextinInputField);
        await element(by.class("ng-binding")).getText().then(async function(text){
            console.log("Expected Text:"+text);
            await expect(text).toEqual(ExpectedTextinInputField);
        });     
});
```

Refer [here](https://www.protractortest.org/#/page-objects) for a clear explanation on creating and executing tests with the protractor.